# Using SWF Address deep linking while adding dynamic meta content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, flash, swfaddress

I have a flash site which reads deep links from the URL, then using c# asp.net we read the url and write the appropriate meta tags for the page being requested.

e.g. GET

> www.domain.com/en-gb/scene4/subscene2

and outputs appropriate meta tags to page

Then we redirect to the swfaddress friendly page containing the '#'

> www.domain.com/#en-gb/scene4/subscene2

I have tried doing this in both webforms and mvc but run into problems both times..Basically I'm a bit lost and could do with some advice or a good example to get inspiration.

**Webforms**
with webforms I would need to create a url mapping for every combination of url paths i could receive or use IIS to redirect all 404 errors to default.aspx.

**MVC**
This seems a more appropriate way of routing the url and obtaining the values however I end up doubling up on my url else i lose my info e.g.

> www.domain.com/en-gb/scene4/subscene2#en-gb/scene4/subscene2

this is not acceptable to use as a url, plus when i create too many paths my flash movie stops displaying.

**Ajax**
Another method I heard is possible is to only use the URLs with the # and not redirect but use Jquery  to read the path after the '#' and an Ajax call to request the meta data from the server side. I haven't tried this path yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this on the MVC route, my problem was on targeting the swf movie on 2nd redirect in JavaScript to /Content. Appears to work well now. On second redirect I don't change window.location if # is present, as stored my model in a session object unless by culture changes.